# Time out on a problem with a dynamic algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am working on an algorithmic problem:
https://leetcode.com/problems/integer-replacement/

```
Given a positive integer n, you can apply one of the following operations:

    If n is even, replace n with n / 2.
    If n is odd, replace n with either n + 1 or n - 1.

Return the minimum number of operations needed for n to become 1.
```

I decided to utilize an iterative dynamic programming approach, so I created a dictionary to keep track of optimal solutions to all overlapping subproblems.
This is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def integerReplacement(self, n: int) -> int:
        
        dic = {1:0}
        
        for i in range(2, n+1):
            #print(i)
            if i % 2 == 0:
                dic[i] = dic[i/2]+1
            else:
                dic[i] = min((dic[(i+1)/2]),(dic[(i-1)/2]))+2
            #print(f"dic[{i}] is {dic[i]}")
                
        return dic[n]
```

I passes 19 cases, but times out on 100000000 input (and 1 time it said that too much space was being used).

So, my question is:
Is my dynamic programming implementation flawed, or is it simply not the way to go in this case?

Thank you

Comment: You compute every intermediate result (approximately 10^8 in your final result). I think there's a simple rule about when to add one rather than subtract one that's something like you only add one if the number you have is 7 mod 8. Think about the binary representation of the number and note the effect of adding or subtracting 1.

Comment: Could you please elaborate where "7 mod 8" comes from in your explanation? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This problem could be solved in O(log(n)) time complexity with O(1) space complexity.*

That's why they are providing large inputs. So, your code couldn't be an optimal choice.

Now, How to solve it:

**1.** if n is even just divide it by 2.

**2.** if n is odd:

**(a)** if **(n-1)//2** results in a number divisible by 2 then this is optimal. But with one edge case i.e.3 then you have to choose (n-1) operation because after division you can reach your target i.e. 1.

**(b)** else n+1 operation because **(n+1)//2** will result in a number divisible by 2.

Here is the code that will pass all the test cases:

```
class Solution:
    def integerReplacement(self, n: int) -> int:
        
        operation = 0
        while(n > 1):
            operation = operation + 1
            if(n%2 == 1):
                if( ((n-1)//2)%2 == 0 or (n-1)//2 == 1):
                    n = n - 1
                else:
                    n = n + 1
            else:
                n = n//2
        
        return operation
```

Comment: Thanks. 
I now understand why dynamic approach is suboptimal for this problem: There is no variance in optimality of the choice for the constituent subproblems--it's always optimal (except for the edge case of 3) to make such a choice that leads us to an even n after the next division by 2 because then division by 2 makes us approach 1 the fastest, and so a simple look-ahead with ((n-1)//2)%2 accomplishes just that.

Comment: @InfiniteLoop Welcome... Yeah, exactly, you got the point.